# USB Drive video protection to copy

Tags: video, usb-drive, copy-protection

I'm looking for a way to protect my video file on a USB/Flash Drive in a way that I can loan it to someone and let him see and watch the video, but disable the option to copy it.
Also since I will use this only in one case and only one time, I am looking for some free solutions if possible.

Or perhaps USB/Flash Drive is not a best option, any other suggestions ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

ProtectUSB Content locks content such as HTML, PDF, Images, Videos, Flash, ePub, Video-DVD, etc. into secure encrypted containers which are then executed in a secure viewer module protected from illegal copies.

[more info...](https://www.protect-software.com/en/solutions/content-protection/usb-stick-content-copy-protection)

Comment: thanks for your answer, since this is a one-time action, does the free trial allow me to make use of it one time ?